# The jquery $("#id").html(data) does't work on firefox, but working on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, firefox

The jquery doesn't work on firefox, but working on chrome.
Mainly the problem is at the line, $("#p1").html(data), it doesn't display the data on browser.
Can anyone help me to figure it out why?

The html code:
1) When I click start button, the backend will send back a string.
2) at handleData, $("#p1").html(data) doesn't display that string on firefox (but on chrome, it is OK).

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleData(data, status) {
        $("#p1").html(data);
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#start").click(function() {
            $.get("testAsync?start=yes", handleData);
        });

        $("#submitResult").click(function() {
            // jquery get the result value.
            var $result = $("#result").val();
            $.get("testAsync?result=" + $result, handleData);
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="content">
        <button id="start">Start Test</button>

        <p id="p1"></p>

        <input type="text" id="result" value="" /> <input type="button"
            id="submitResult" value="Submit" />
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing parameters to the callback function?

Comment: @greener: arguments are passed by `$.get`.

Comment: Firefox occasionally has stricter security and privacy controls than chrome. It's possible that your ajax request is being blocked somehow. Can you post a jsfiddle? Or post the actual request and response sent by each browser?

Comment: @thesystem learned something! thanks.

Comment: is any exception thrown out? firebug may help

Comment: Maybe you have a problem with `Same Origin Policy` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy): Firefox understands address with and without "www" differently.. Try to use an absolute path (depending on the presence or not of www) in your `$.get` request.

Comment: Firebug shows me that "data" is Document even though the backend server returns a string. How to 'get' the string from Document in my case?

Comment: Found a workaround. It looks like Firefox is very strict with the "content-type", and if I don't specify it, it thinks "text/xml", and thus it caused the browser doesn't render it properly. <br/> If I set it to "text/html", then I can see the data displayed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Firefox is very strict with the **"content-type"**, and if I don't specify it, it thinks **"text/xml"**, and thus it caused the browser doesn't render it properly. 
 If I set it to **"text/html"**, then I can see the data displayed.

Comment: Can you plz share ho you specify the 'content-type'?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add your return DataType to the $.get
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
Firefox may be "guessing" (yes the jQuery API says this) the return type wrong.

Comment: I tried this, $("#p1").html($.get(data)), and it still doesn't work. As I said in another reply. If I specify the "content-type" as "text/html", then FF worked also.